# Washer method around X-axis vs other axis

Tags: calculus

I had a question I was hoping someone could answer. I'm working on this homework problem, and when graphed, the volume looks like it would be the same revolving around the x-axis or on the axis of $y=5$, but it isn't. Why is this?

Problem:
Find the volume of region R when region R is revolved about the line $y = 4$ . Region R is defined as the region enclosed by the graphs of $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 2x$ .

The correct volume is $\dfrac{32}{5}\pi$

[image: Graphed Problem]

Comment: Why do you think that would look the same revolved around both axes? Have you tried sketching it by hand? (It's not the same shape).

Comment: Revolved around the x axis the volume would look like a cone with a “trumpet bell” shaped piece taken out of it, but revolved around the line y=5 it would look like a pointed dome with a cone removed from the interior.

Comment: Is the axis of revolution $y=4$ or $y=5$? There's conflicting info here